# How do I determine if a widget is being used?

Tags: extensions, widget

I'm cleaning up an extension which appears to effectively do nothing; the one remaining component to be removed is a widget, but I'm unsure how I would determine if the widget is used.

What tactic would I need to follow to confirm whether or not the widget is in use in the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep the entire Magento installation for widget type (e.g. `cms/widget_block`). Then dump content of `cms_block` and `cms_page` tables and grep it for the same string.

If you have EE you may also bother about `enterprise_cms_page_revision` but if I were you I wouldn't.